# Gold coins with face value greater than the metal value — what's the catch?

Tags: gold, coins, precious-metals

If you're going to keep some money in cash, is there any downside to keeping it in gold coins that you can buy at their face value, where that face value is higher than the metal value?

I came across [this €1000 coin](https://www.monnaiedeparis.fr/en/shop/coins/marianne-liberty-1000eu-gold-coin-brilliant-uncirculated-quality-yeardate-2017), which can actually be bought for €1000. It contains 17 grams of gold, worth about €600 today. Is there any **downside** to this over keeping €1000 in regular banknotes? (Other than the practical challenges of getting a bank to accept it, I guess.)

The potential **upside** is, of course, that the metal may eventually be worth more than the face value. (Of course, if you're keeping many of these for a long time there would be some storage costs, like with any physical metal.)

Comment: The main downside I can think of vs banknote*s* is that you can't easily spend it. You'd have to exchange it at a bank for smaller denominations that merchants will accept. Compared to a *single* €1000 banknote however, there is not really any downside, it's certainly more durable, which is a good thing.

Comment: I'd be careful with 'face value' - it just means the coin _shows that number on it_. This could well be some worthless collectible where you struggle to find anyone paying you just the 'gold value' for it.

Comment: @Aganju the key terminology here is "legal tender" and "circulated" (or "uncirculated"). All legal tender is worth its face value for repaying debts, meaning a creditor cannot refuse such a coin as settlement for a debt. In real life however, currency is more often used for immediate transactions, not settling debts, and in that situation a merchant is allowed to refuse any method of payment that they don't like, for any reason or no reason at all. Circulated coins are generally acceptable though, and even uncirculated coins can still be accepted, but it's at the merchant's discretion.

Comment: @CactusCake , i am well aware of that. _Legal Tender_ is not mentioned in the offer. _Not Circulated_ has no meaning, as any collectible is _not circulated_ when you buy it. I just warned the OP, _face value_ means _nothing_ - I can write '1000 Euro' on a piece of paper and declare it has a face value of that.

Comment: What do you mean "practical challenges"?  Either it's money, or it's not. There is no "challenge" that will make a bank take something that is not money.  Gold is not money. Also not money is a Beanie Baby or this overpriced collectible.  Have you ever tried actually selling collectibles?  If you want to learn collectibles trading, start ...smaller...

Comment: Have you ever tried using a €500 banknote? Those "practical challenges"... x 10.

Answer (score 6):

> I came across this €1000 coin, which can actually be bought for €1000. It contains 17 grams of gold, worth about €600 today. Is there any downside to this over keeping €1000 in regular banknotes?

These are bullions / medallions / collectibles / Non Circulating Tenders or whatever name one wants to call it. A coin has a value because the Central Banks says so that enforces everyone accept it at that.

This as such is not a coin. Banks or anyone else will not accept this for face value.

These are of numismatic interest and certain people do collect such items. They are collectibles to the extent the price is dependent on general interest in future on such items and quantity available. So if future the price may go up much higher than the gold price or may retain its gold price.

Mints make these with intricate design, best finish, limited quantity to charge the additional premium.

If you are not into numismatics, stay away, a better options is buy simple gold bullion of similar weight for actual gold price.

Comment: So that coin is not legal tender, basically? If so, it seems like a borderline scam for them to call it a "1000€ Face value coin"!

Comment: @EM0: Well, isn't that the "value" listed on the "face"? Think of it like a Manufacturers Suggested Retail Price, just like that which is printed on the packaging of many items, but it doesn't mean that any particular person is forced to buy it from you for that price.

Comment: @EM0 It looks like coins minted at Monnaie de Paris *are* legal tender, but you should definitely familiarize yourself with what that term [means](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/legal-tender.asp) and, perhaps more importantly, what it [doesn't](http://www.news-leader.com/story/news/watchdog/2014/12/24/ask-watchdog-can-business-refuse-cash/20883777/).

Comment: Note that in the US, even coins listed as having a "suggested value" on the face and not showing any resemblance to actual US coins have been confiscated with the [creators charged with Counterfeiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_dollar_%28private_currency%29#Indictment). I have no idea what the EU law or practice on the issue is.

Comment: @CactusCake That's interesting. How did you confirm that they're legal tender? And if they are, OK, obviously a sandwich shop can refuse to accept a €1000 gold coin (indeed, I'd be very surprised if they accepted it!), but can a French bank (that ordinarily allows cash deposits) refuse to accept it?

Comment: @EM0 Yes, there is at least one French bank that will exchange them for you; see "Collector Coins" on [page 4 of this document](https://www.banque-france.fr/fileadmin/user_upload/banque_de_france/La_Banque_de_France/NI138-en.pdf). The rest of the document also discusses "Legal Tender".

Comment: Great work on finding that, thanks! So apparently you can get the "face value" of that coin... at least in Paris... at least in theory. I can imagine that in practice they would ask you to prove 50 different ways that you obtained the coins legitimately. Maybe not for 1, but if you're trying to deposit 100 of them - good luck!

Comment: @CactusCake "Banque de France" is the Central Bank in France. Similar to Fed of US.

Comment: Also note that these coins are produced by France's national mint (from the website of the OP's original link: "_Monnaie de Paris's sovereign mission for the state is to strike circulating coinage. It holds the monopoly on French euros_") so as noted on the "Collector Coins" section, these _are_ legal tender (but only in France, not in the rest of the EU) and will always be "worth" €1,000. Other clues: on the product page, they are described as "coins"... in the UK (at least), this would not be legal if they weren't official.